# I am trying to get the value using JSON in android, Below is my code, It shows null pointer exception and error during request queue

Tags: android

```
/**
     * Method to make json array request where response starts with [
     * Requesting data from url
     * */

private String urlJsonArry_local = "http://www.endorecord.in/endorecord/hospitaladmin/Api/device_hospitals.php?deviceid=";



private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

    showpDialog();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry_local +androidID,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        jsonResponse = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                    .get(i);

                            String name = person.getString("hospitalid");
                            String email = person.getString("hospital_name");

                            /*JSONObject phone = person
                                    .getJSONObject("phone");
                            String home = phone.getString("home");
                            String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                            */

                            jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                            //jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                            //jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant lines from your LogCat, and tell us which lines correspond to the ones reported in LogCat.

Comment: Bro below you can find my logcat, i think the problem is in line            11-24 13:42:34.220: E/AndroidRuntime(22142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.networksys.doclogin/com.networksys.doclogin.ActivityMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

you should be passing your url in the request `"http://www.google.com"+androidID` not this. And the Url `urlJsonArry_local` that you have mentioned above returns json object response not jsonArray, Your code and Json reponse are completely irrelavant

for the Json respone in above url

private String urlJsonArry_local = "http://www.endorecord.in/endorecord/hospitaladmin/Api/device_hospitals.php?deviceid=";

```
RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,urlJsonArry_local,null/* paramateres passed here*/,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

             JSONObject jObject = response;
             String status = jObject.getString("status");
             JSONArray hospitalArray = jObject.getJSONArray("hospital");

              //your for loop to parse hospital array here

             hideProgressDialog();
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             hideProgressDialog();
        }
    });
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: @Nafeel do have any custom class with the same name?? The sample is same as in android [official site](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) take a look at it

Comment: Application Force close

Comment: can you post the logcat, Have you provided internet permission in manifest